# WebRequest to check server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I am trying to check if my server (local server) is up or down. 
I want to pass my server name: myDEVServer12 (http://www.example.com/ss.asp)

```
Public Function CheckServer(ByVal ServerName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(ServerName)
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        imgServer1.ImageUrl = ("~/Images/green_light.png")
    Catch ex As Exception
        imgServer1.ImageUrl = ("~/Images/red_light.png")
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

I also tried to use ping. It works, but the page takes a long time to load (4 servers)

```
Dim ping As New Ping
Try
    Dim pingreply = ping.Send(lblServer1.Text, 2000)
    If pingreply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
        imgServer1.ImageUrl = ("~/Images/green_light.png")
    Else
        imgServer1.ImageUrl = ("~/Images/red_light.png")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    imgServer1.ImageUrl = ("~/Images/red_light.png")
End Try
```

Comment: Decrease the timeout on your ping method, 200 should be sufficient. For multiple servers you could thread the requests for faster completion time as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim myRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com")
' Return the response. 
Dim myResponse As String = myRequest.GetResponse().ContentType().ToString()
MsgBox(myResponse)
```

Comment: Use indenting to format the code please. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).